# upgrade from 18.04 LTS to 20.04

Tags: upgrade

I would like to upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 LTS. I use the command. sudo do-release-upgrade. I get a message, that I have first to install all updates for the version 18.04. But I have done that. Only one third party Program can`t be updated to newest Version because it need the Ubuntu 20.04 version. Have I first to remove that Software?

```
Neue Veröffentlichungen von Ubuntu werden gesucht
Bitte installieren Sie alle erhältlichen Aktualisierungen für Ihre Version bevor Sie eine Systemaktualisierung durchführen.
udo@i-base:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade
[sudo] Passwort für udo: 
OK:1 h://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
OK:2 h://apt.symcon.de stable InRelease                                     
OK:3 h://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease              
OK:4 h://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease            
Holen:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]  
Holen:6 h://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [55,1 kB]
Holen:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [61,1 kB]
Holen:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2.464 B]
Es wurden 207 kB in 9 s geholt (23,5 kB/s).   
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Aktualisierung für 1 Paket verfügbar. Führen Sie »apt list --upgradable« aus, um es anzuzeigen.
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut.       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen.... Fertig
Paketaktualisierung (Upgrade) wird berechnet... Fertig
Die folgenden Pakete wurden automatisch installiert und werden nicht mehr benötigt:
  libllvm8 libllvm9 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-100
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-104 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-105
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-107 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-109
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-42 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-45
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-47 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-48
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-51 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-52
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-53 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-54
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-56 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-58
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-59 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-60
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-62 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-64
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-65 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-66
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-67 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-70
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-71 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-72
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-73 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-74
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-77 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-80
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-81 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-84
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-86 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-87
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-89 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-90
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-91 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-92
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-94 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-96
  linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-97 linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-99 shim
Verwenden Sie »sudo apt autoremove«, um sie zu entfernen.
Die folgenden Pakete werden aktualisiert (Upgrade):
  symcon
1 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
Es müssen noch 0 B von 21,4 MB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 0 B Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] j
(Lese Datenbank ... 913428 Dateien und Verzeichnisse sind derzeit installiert.)
Vorbereitung zum Entpacken von .../symcon_6.2-229_amd64.deb ...
IP-Symcon is running.
Stopping...
IP-Symcon stopped
At least Ubuntu (20.04) is required to install this update!
Press any key to continue... 
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Archivs /var/cache/apt/archives/symcon_6.2-229_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 »neues symcon-Skript des Paketes pre-installation«-Unterprozess gab den Fehlerwert 1 zurück
IP-Symcon is not running.
Starting...
IP-Symcon started with PID 16854
Open the console to start configuration:
h://192.168.178.61:3777/console/
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/symcon_6.2-229_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have changed http into h, because it´s not possible to post so many links.

---

The upgrade process starts and it looks quiet good, but a message again appear that the same third party software can`t be updated,because the newest version need ubuntu 20.04. It`s the ip-symcon software again.

Hello together,
thank you for your help. I have to remove the software and after that the upgrade procedure works well.

Comment: Start by doing `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`. Then try the release upgrade. If the problem persists then please [edit] the question and describe what is that 3rd party software and why do you believe it can't be updated.

Comment: Maybe some of the snapd services aren't running

Comment: The package installed from a 3rd party repository `apt.symcon.de ` is causing the problem, obviously. You can try disabling the repo by opening Software and Updates, going to the Other Software tab, and unticking the box beside that repository. Let it update the list of sources when you close the app, then try the upgrade again. If it still doesn't work, uninstall the package.

Comment: and please, you have many kernels on your system. `sudo apt autoremove --purge`